# Django view not rendering after Ajax redirect

Tags: python, ajax, django, redirect, django-views

The main page of my website has multiple buttons at the top. Whenever one of these buttons is pushed, a get request is sent to a django view, which is redirected and a queryset of django models is filtered and eventually displayed on the web page. I know that my ajax works because the terminal says the request is redirected properly. The function it redirects to also seems to be working, as it is quite simple and has not thrown any errors. However, my view remains the same and I'm not sure why.

urls.py

```
url(r'ajax_filter/', views.ajax_filter, name='ajax_filter'),
url(r'filter=(\w+)/$', views.filtered_index, name='filtered_index'),
```

views.py

```
def filtered_index(request, filter):
    clothes = Clothes_Item.objects.filter(gender=filter)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        favorite_clothes_ids = get_favorite_clothes_ids(request)
        return render(request, 'test.html', {'clothes': clothes, 'favorite_clothes_ids': favorite_clothes_ids})
    else:
        return render(request, 'test.html', {'clothes': clothes, })

def ajax_filter(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        gender_filter = request.GET.get('gender_filter') #filter type
        if gender_filter is not None:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('filtered_index', args=[gender_filter]))
    return HttpResponse('')
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can not use Django redirect in your case. When you send an ajax request you usually expect a json response, and based on that you can redirect the user via your JavaScript code.

```
$.ajax({
  // You send your request here
}).done(function(data) {
  // You can handle your redirection here
});
```

---

Here is how you can handle a redirect with your setup, you pass back a JsonResponse from django with the next page that you want to go to:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def ajax_filter(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        gender_filter = request.GET.get('gender_filter') #filter type
        if gender_filter is not None:
            return JsonResponse({
                'success': True,
                'url': reverse('filtered_index', args=[gender_filter]),
            })
    return JsonResponse({ 'success': False })
```

In JS, you use done (or success) function to grab the URL from the passed back `JsonResponse` and redirect to that URL using `window.location.href`:

```
$.ajax({
  // You send your request here
}).done(function (data) {
    if (data.success) {
        window.location.href = data.url;
    }    
});
```

Comment: How should I handle the redirection in the second part of the code you wrote above?

Comment: Return a JsonResponse in your view and return the next URL that you want to redirect to.  In your JavaScript, use window.location.href to do the redirection on the client.

Comment: As @2ps mentioned, you can use `window.location.href = your_url`.

Comment: @aettanany : thanks for your code, well working. What about adding a context ? If I want to show something new in the template (refreshing the initial page). I tried passing a context and request through HttpRedirect but it's not Json Serializable. Any Idea ?