# Django: how to make view only be visited when redirected

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-urls

Hi I have been reading this [Django view not rendering after Ajax redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273295/django-view-not-rendering-after-ajax-redirect) and have code as below that intends to redirect to `/main` if successfully authenticated or alert if otherwise.

otplogin.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
{% load static %}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet"></link>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="otplogin">
     <form class="form-horizontal" id="getotp" >
          {% csrf_token %} 
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"  placeholder="Username">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <button type="submit" value='auth'  class="btn">Auth</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="otp">OTP</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="otp" name="otp" id="otp" placeholder="OTP">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <button type="submit" value='login'  class="btn">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn").click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault() // cancel form submission
        if ($(this).attr("value") == "auth") {
            console.log("CHECK 1");
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/getotp2',
                data:{
                    username:$('#username').val()
                    ,csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                },
                success: function server_response(response) {
                //console.log('POST1 success')
                }
            });
        }
        else if ($(this).attr("value") == "login") {
            console.log("CHECK 2");
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/otpcheck',
                data:{
                    username:$('#username').val(),
                    otp:$('#otp').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
                },
               success: function server_response(response) {
                const r = JSON.parse(response);
                console.log(r.authresult);
                if (r.authresult=='success'){
                window.location.href='/main'; //also tried with './main','../main',''http://127.0.0.1:8000/main', none worked
            } else{
                alert("Auth Failed");
                }
            }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
def otplogin(request):
    return render(request,'esearch/otplogin.html')

def getotp2(request):
    logout(request)
    global otp
    username =otp = ''
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username','')
        otp = pyotp.TOTP('base32secret3232').now()
        OTPEmail('You Auth',username,[],'Your auth is '+otp)
        print ('POST'+username)
        print ('POST'+otp)
        return JsonResponse(json.dumps({'username':username,'otp':otp}),safe=False)

def otpcheck(request):
    if request.POST:
        otpentered=request.POST.get('otp','')
        print(otpentered)
        authresult='fail'
        if otpentered==otp:
            authresult='success'
            print('POST'+authresult)

        else:
            print('POST'+authresult)
        return JsonResponse(json.dumps({'authresult':authresult}),safe=False)

@login_required(login_url='/otplogin')
def search_index(request):
     ######
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('main', views.search_index, name='main'),
    path('otplogin', views.otplogin,name="otplogin"),
    path('getotp2', views.getotp2, name="getotp2"),
    path('otpcheck', views.otpcheck, name="otpcheck"),]
```

Console prints everything fine, but the page get redirected to `http://localhost:8000/otplogin?next=/main` instead of wanted `http://localhost:8000/main`. If I remove `@login_required(login_url='/otplogin')`, it redirects successfully but I want the `/main` page to be visited by user only after getting `success` in `authresult`. So how can I make a Django view be visited only as the result of redirection from other pages. Thanks.

Comment: Do you get the same error if using a different browser?

Comment: @TiagosupportsGoFundMonica Tried on Chrome and Firefox, same error

Comment: Can you share the HTML?

Comment: @TiagosupportsGoFundMonica  Added in the question

Comment: By adding `@login_required(login_url="/optlogin/") ` means that if the user isn't logged in will be redirected to optlogin. Are you testing with a user logged in?

Comment: @TiagosupportsGoFundMonica  I am testing with a user logging in from  my `otplogin` page, not Django login.  If this is not allowed in Django, can you tell me how to have the page hidden unless redirected? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want the first page to be in browser history, you can instead of the `window.location.href` property,  use `window.location.replace("http://localhost:8000/main");`.

Comment: @TiagosupportsGoFundMonica  The `main` can be in the browser history but user has to login from `otplogin` to get there. I just used `window.location.replace("http://localhost:8000/main");` while keeping `@login_required(login_url="/optlogin")`, same error.

Comment: Not sure how are you knowing if user has login, so if `window.location.replace` makes it invalid or not. Can you clear browser cache and try again?

Comment: @TiagosupportsGoFundMonica  The user will be 'logged in' and redirected to `/main` if the otp entered is the same as  the one sent, which means getting `success` in `authresult`. Cleared the cache and tried again and it is still the same.

Comment: The html you shared is optlogin.html?

Comment: @TiagosupportsGoFundMonica Yes. Sorry if not clear. Just updated in the question.

Comment: For any reason you have `{% load static %}` before `<!DOCTYPE html><html>`? Also, the initial links and scripts should be wrapped inside <head></head> and you're also forgetting to put the page content (including the last script) inside of <body></body>.

Comment: @TiagosupportsGoFundMonica Thanks for pointing this out. I am still an amateur learning by doing at the moment. Updated my code and still same error.

Comment: It was not about the JS part, but on the backend. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818402/make-view-accessible-only-through-redirect-and-from-only-one-view-in-django